# Change a major tick label

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I've drawn this chart from an API, so I can't provide the data. The x axis are dates and prices like this:

```
            price
date
2022-12-18   1.19
2022-12-19   1.19
2022-12-20   1.19
2022-12-21   1.19
2022-12-22   1.19
```

[image]

What I want to change is what is in the red circle from "Jan\n2023" to "Jan-23" the rest is ok. What I've used in the code is this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6), constrained_layout=True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
   mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=(15)))

data_toplot.plot(ax=ax)

for label in ax.get_xticklabels(which='major'):
    label.set(rotation=0, horizontalalignment='center')
```

But I don't know what is called to look for it myself because you can see the the days are minor ticks are that day is a major tick but also the one on the 18 a 3 day. So I don't know what function to use.

Comment: That looks like formatting applied by pandas (since you are using `DataFrame.plot`), btw

Comment: Yes I'm using pandas but you I think you should be able to change the major tick in matplotlit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to illustrate one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ["2022-12-18", "2022-12-19", "2022-12-20", "2022-12-21", "2022-12-22"],
        "price": [1.19, 2.19, 5.19, 3.19, 4.19],
    }
)
```

```py
# Plot dataframe as is

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df["date"], df["price"])
```

Output:

[image]

```py
# Plot the dataframe, but replace tick "2022-12-21" with "9999-99-99"
plt.xticks(
    ticks=range(df["date"].shape[0]),
    labels=[x if x != "2022-12-21" else "99-99-9999" for x in df["date"]],
)
plt.plot(df["date"], df["price"])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As I read in some other SO answer, `pandas.plot` and custom dates format don't go too well together so i just went to pure `matplotlib`